# How do I create multiple questions and hidden answers for my FAQ?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a FAQ for a forum and I am using show and hide methods with jQuery. I would like to know how to make multiple questions and answers for each one of my FAQ. By default, the answer should be hidden until someone clicks on the question. I attempted to use display: none; in CSS but this has no impact. Basically, I want my FAQ function like Google Wallet's FAQ: https://www.google.com/wallet/faq/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-bottom-width: inherit;
  border-right-width: inherit;
  outline-color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Question: How do I get a gold star?</button>

<p>Answer: This depends on a number of things.</p>
```

Comment: What you are describing is an accordion or collapse script. This is not hard to research

Answer (score 0):

Set the display property for p to none;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).next("p").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-bottom-width: inherit;
  border-right-width: inherit;
  outline-color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Question: How do I get a gold star?</button>

<p>Answer: This depends on a number of things.</p>
```